# How to fix getcolor and geticon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
 builder: (controller)=>InkWell(
           onTap:  controller.checkIsQuestionAnswerd(questionsID)? null: onPressed,
           child: Container(
             width: double.infinity,
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
               border: Border.all(width: 3,
                   color: controller.getColor(index))),
             child: Padding(
               padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
               child: Row(
                 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                 children: [
                   RichText(
                     text: TextSpan(
                         text: '${index + 1}. ',
                         style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                         children: [
                           TextSpan(
                             text: text,
                             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                           ),
                         ]),
                   ),
                   if (controller.checkIsQuestionAnswerd(questionsID) &&
                       controller.selectedAnswer == index)
                     Container(
                         width: 30,
                         height: 30,
                         padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                         alignment: Alignment.center,
                         decoration: BoxDecoration(
                             color: controller.getColor(index),
                             border: Border.all(
                               color: Colors.white,
                               width: 3,
                             ),
                             shape: BoxShape.circle
                         ),
                         child: Icon(
                           controller.getIcon(index),
                           color: Colors.white,
```

Comment: Can you describe the current behavior and your expected behavior from the snippet and about `controller.getColor(index)`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.